# Pandas str.extract returning NaN

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have the following `df`

```
Trends                       Value   
2021-12-13T08:00:00.000Z       45
2021-12-13T07:00:00.000Z       32
2021-12-13T06:42:10.000Z       23
2021-12-13T06:27:00.000Z       45
2021-12-10T05:00:00.000Z       23
```

I ran the following line:

```
df['Trends'].str.extract('^(.*:[1-9][1-9].*)$', expand=True)
```

It returns:

```
0
NaN  
NaN   
2021-12-13T06:42:10.000Z  
2021-12-13T06:27:00.000Z   
NaN
```

My objective is to use the regex, extract any trends that have minutes and seconds more than zero. The regex works (tested) and the line also work, but what I don't understand is why is it returning `NaN` when it does not match? I looked through several other SO and the line is pretty much the same.

My expected outcome:

```
2021-12-13T06:42:10.000Z  
2021-12-13T06:27:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is close; you can get matches with str.match, then filter:

`df[df.Trends.str.match('^(.*:[1-9][1-9].*)$')].Trends`

output:

```
2    2021-12-13T06:42:10.000Z
3    2021-12-13T06:27:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

previous answer won't work with the following data (where minute is 00 but second is not, or vice versa), but will work with this updated regex.

`df[df.Trends.str.match('^(?!.*:00:00\..*)(.*:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\..*)$')].Trends`

or

`df[df.Trends.str.match('^(?!.*:00:00\..*)(.*:.*\..*)$')].Trends`

or if second doesn't matter, but 01 minute should be selected then

`df[df.Trends.str.match('^(?!.*:00:\d+\..*)(.*:.*\..*)$')].Trends`

```
Trends                       Value   
2021-12-13T07:00:00.000Z       32
2021-12-13T07:00:01.000Z       32
2021-12-13T07:00:10.000Z       32
2021-12-13T07:01:00.000Z       32
2021-12-13T07:10:00.000Z       32
```